# Cannot identify this plant

Tags: identification, houseplants

Can you please help me identify this plant? I've tried to google around but I cannot find it.

[image: My plant]

Answer (score 4):

Based on the dotty leaves, the flower and the growth structure it is most probably a *Begonia*.

I am not sure what species but it looks like a *Begonia maculata* "Madagascar" to me.

Comment: Agree - definitely a begonia, and one that needs more light than it's getting. +1

Comment: I have heard them called "angel wing" begonias .